# Algorithm for a 5 star rating system

Tags: quantiles, recommender-system

I'm creating a reporting tool that produces a data set and calculates a metric for each item in the data set. I have two algorithms that I'm working with: an algorithm that produces the metric and an algorithm that produces a rating(1-5 star rating) for visual representation of the calculated metric.

The algorithm to calculate the Metric will be fine-tuned on an ongoing basis. It's a prediction tool, so I will constantly compare the metric to real data and modify the algorithm accordingly.

On the other hand, I'd like the Rating algorithm to remain somewhat consistent. My initial approach to the Rating algorithm was to use a percentile function similar to Excel's to find the value at: 98th percentile(5 stars), 90th(4 stars), 75%(3 stars), etc.

Here is the function I used. (This is the Ruby programming language, but it should be readable enough to get the jist of it)

```
def percentile(values, percentile)
    values_sorted = values.sort
    k = (percentile*(values_sorted.length-1)+1).floor - 1
    f = (percentile*(values_sorted.length-1)+1).modulo(1)

    return values_sorted[k] + (f * (values_sorted[k+1] - values_sorted[k]))
  end
```

If I understand this equation correctly, it's producing a percentile value based on the number of items rather than the actual values of the items. Typically, I will have a data set with 150 items. This is a poor method of calculating a Rating because it will always produce exactly 3 five star items. I need a better approach that will calculate a Rating based on the actual Metric values. Any ideas?

Here are a few sample data sets:

Sample 1 - 150 items

```
2,466,505
1,118,729
935,150
431,367
271,558
243,603
168,266
166,507
164,543
137,216
132,801
120,329
109,000
103,088
101,341
89,685
80,173
74,703
70,748
66,970
63,408
60,368
54,433
54,184
51,760
46,812
45,659
43,140
42,682
41,864
40,151
39,989
35,766
34,020
33,379
32,803
29,393
28,791
28,570
27,724
27,341
26,282
24,431
23,537
22,804
22,634
22,217
21,812
21,648
21,230
20,657
20,312
19,602
18,157
17,924
17,398
16,771
15,359
15,238
15,156
15,156
15,126
15,068
14,654
14,300
14,109
13,924
13,893
12,813
12,612
12,419
12,236
11,736
11,586
11,367
10,349
10,297
9,988
9,900
9,112
8,453
8,420
7,912
7,893
7,525
7,484
7,440
7,429
6,736
6,518
6,497
6,174
5,613
5,473
5,242
5,067
4,657
4,262
4,152
4,104
4,069
4,052
4,052
4,045
3,990
3,952
3,814
3,621
3,387
3,280
3,280
3,189
2,806
2,804
2,789
2,701
2,701
2,540
2,476
2,320
2,320
2,227
2,129
2,064
2,020
1,989
1,951
1,878
1,783
1,713
1,641
1,590
1,341
1,341
1,341
1,326
1,248
1,105
1,030
912
723
609
482
368
314
237
74
65
34
28
```

Sample 2 - 150 items

```
 3,553,644 
 723,572 
 356,706 
 321,258 
 184,440 
 173,914 
 133,995 
 117,048 
 101,442 
 87,061 
 80,692 
 62,248 
 39,193 
 32,277 
 31,656 
 29,794 
 27,932 
 27,666 
 26,792 
 26,604 
 25,438 
 23,459 
 22,612 
 22,346 
 22,249 
 21,104 
 20,949 
 19,508 
 18,533 
 17,380 
 16,582 
 16,582 
 16,138 
 14,897 
 14,631 
 14,631 
 13,996 
 13,656 
 12,985 
 12,104 
 12,104 
 11,731 
 11,627 
 10,729 
 10,182 
 9,822 
 9,154 
 9,062 
 8,876 
 8,415 
 8,415 
 8,069 
 7,819 
 7,645 
 7,200 
 7,162 
 6,840 
 6,172 
 6,172 
 5,657 
 5,574 
 5,544 
 5,303 
 5,143 
 5,089 
 4,946 
 4,946 
 4,895 
 4,895 
 4,895 
 4,895 
 4,685 
 4,564 
 4,357 
 4,256 
 4,180 
 3,752 
 3,671 
 3,628 
 3,482 
 3,386 
 3,339 
 3,104 
 3,009 
 2,979 
 2,979 
 2,913 
 2,902 
 2,554 
 2,451 
 2,314 
 2,217 
 2,147 
 1,951 
 1,951 
 1,874 
 1,862 
 1,756 
 1,664 
 1,643 
 1,561 
 1,561 
 1,561 
 1,561 
 1,561 
 1,561 
 1,483 
 1,426 
 1,419 
 1,419 
 1,345 
 1,341 
 1,330 
 1,330 
 1,277 
 1,234 
 1,229 
 1,194 
 1,170 
 1,170 
 1,158 
 1,149 
 1,149 
 1,146 
 1,135 
 1,117 
 1,117 
 1,064 
 958 
 859 
 851 
 851 
 766 
 721 
 681 
 638 
 585 
 575 
 575 
 479 
 383 
 383 
 319 
 284 
 276 
 234 
 211 
 195 
 44 
 44
```

Sample 3 - 58 items

```
60,349
43,949
31,562
24,505
17,767
16,928
14,801
11,564
10,695
9,567
8,883
8,712
7,572
7,468
7,340
7,302
6,638
6,472
6,223
5,974
5,808
5,744
5,476
5,393
3,717
3,566
3,556
3,368
3,242
3,126
2,863
2,626
2,613
2,555
2,409
2,391
2,351
2,309
2,125
2,042
1,936
1,825
1,797
1,659
1,521
1,475
1,294
1,171
1,120
1,045
878
757
631
543
461
431
426
237
```

Comment: I do not understand the question :( ? 1. What does the sample represent (why do exist 1-3 values per line) ? 2. Is it correct that the metric values do reflect the quality of the prediction ? If so, why can't you use the metric values directly, why an extra rating ? What shall the rating express, for example what is 1 star and what is 5 star ?

Comment: 1. There is only 1 value per line. Some of the values are in the thousands/millions. The value represents the "importance" of the item. 2. The rating system is really for curb appeal for a consumer facing website.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure we're well placed to answer this question as it really isn't a stats question - it's a user interface question.

You're trying to find a mapping from (what looks like) the set of integers to a five star rating. But to do that we really need to know *what those five stars mean*. It looks like, from you reply above, it's to recommend something to consumers on a website. Okay. For the sake of argument then, let's define the best way of rating items as *the one which most closely matches how a user would rate them*.

To do that you're going to need to get some data on how users rate items. There's no way around this, unless you have some strong prior knowledge that you're not sharing with us. Assuming not the best way to do that is get hold of some data that indicates the answer directly, i.e.

- Get a bunch of test items.
- Have some 'typical users' rate them.
- And calculate your metric score for each.

So now you have a set of pairs of readings for each item - user score and metric evaluation. You now need to choose a way of turning those metric score for each item into a star rating that 'most closely' (for some notion of closely) matches the user supplied score. There's about a bazillion different ways to do that. I've put an example using model fitting between the tildas below:

~

As the metric scores are numeric, I'm going to assume they're well approximate by a set of five normal distributions, one per star rating. As such I'll fit a gaussian to the set of metric scores corresponding to each star rating, then classify novel metrics according to the most probable star rating.

Let's take all the items that users rated five star and calculate their metric scores. We have a dataset for the five star rated items that looks like $\{m_1^{5*}, m_2^{5*}, \ldots m_{N_5}^{5*} \}$ where $m_1^{5*}$ is the metric score of the first item that was rated five stars, $m_2^{5*}$ the second, etc. In total, the number of items which got rated as five star by users is $N_5$.

The ML parameters of the gaussian we fit to this are just
$$
\mu^{5*} = \frac{1}{N_5}\sum_{n=1}^{N_5} m_n^{5*}
$$

$$
\sigma^{5*} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{N_5}\sum_{n=1}^{N_5} \left( m_n^{5*} - \mu^{5*} \right)^2}
$$
as usual. As such, we can say 
$$
P(m|5*) = N(m|\mu^{5*}, \sigma^{5*})
$$

Our ML star rating prior is just 
$$
P(5*) = \frac{N_5}{N_1+N_2+N_3+N_4+N_5}
$$ 
where $N_1$ is the number of one star rated items, and so on. As such we can get the joint probability $P(m,5*) = P(m|5*)P(5*)$

Do this for all the star ratings. When you come to runtime and you have a novel item to assign a star rating to, find its metric score (call that $m_{new}$), and then calculate the set of five probabilities $P(m_{new},5*)$, $P(m_{new},4*)$, $\ldots$ $P(m_{new},1*)$. The most probable star rating is simply the one which has the  highest joint probability - so, if  $P(m_{new},4*)$ was higher than all the others, you would assign the item corresponding to $m_{new}$ four stars (this corresponds to the MAP assignment). That's it.

This method should be scalable and not too hard hard to implement - you just need to calculate five means, five standard deviations, and five class priors, and be able to evaluate a normal distribution at run time. You'll need to re-estimate the parameters each time you change your metric, but that should be very quick. Additionally, the more user generated scores you can get, the more accurate the rating scheme will become.

~

That's a quick example, based on the assumption you want your star ratings to match those a user would supply. *Maybe you don't*. Maybe you want to maximise click through. Maybe your users get frustrated if the first item they click isn't right, so you want to ensure the 5* ratings are the best possible. Maybe a nuclear power plant melts down if the 1* rated items aren't attended to promptly. I don't know. But you very much need to think about it and decide what your star rating is going to do. Once you know exactly what it's going to do though, I suspect an answer as to how to implement it will become clear very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to do would be to define a "metric z-score", i.e. for each item score $x_i$
$$
z_i = \frac{ x_i - \bar{x} }{ s }
$$

where $\bar{x}$ and $s$ are the average and empirical standard deviation of the full set of item scores.

Then your ratings could correspond to cutoffs of the $z$ scores, say < -3, -3 to -1, -1 to 1, 1 to 3, and > 3.

This avoids the "equal groupings" problem of percentiles, and also gives a fixed interpretation to the ratings even as the underlying metric changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a good approach for you, if your process meets some assumptions...

If the numbers are generated from some input data that you can easily generate random input values for (i.e. based on a distribution, or based on recombining attributes from your sample data), just generate a few hundred to a few thousand "random" sets of input values, run your process on these to get a bunch of fake outputs, then use the percentiles (e.g. 90%,75%,60%,35%) from this distribution as the cutoff points for your ratings.

This has the benefit that:

1. It adapts to the changes in the prediction model over time.
2. If your predictions for your objects are still ordered the same over time, then the ratings will remain fairly stable.
3. It recognizes that a set of outputs may have more good values in it than others (you don't get three 5-stars every time)
4. It doesn't require an assumption that your outputs are normally distributed

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether I do understand your question right, but  I think a quantile normalization could be a useful approach for you.

Use quantile normalization to sort your data (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_normalization) into different bins. Every bin would represent a certain rating.